# How to simplify complex nested do-loops?

Tags: optimization, fortran, matrix-multiplication, do-loops

I have very tedious task to optimize some ancient Fortran77 code. Honestly, I don't know fortran at all. I know how loops works and how to multiply matrices. I also know that this loop can be optimized to few 3-4 nested loops:

```
    do i = 1, nocca
     do j = 1, nocca
       do k = 1, noccb                                                                                                               
         do l = 1, noccc
           do m = 1, nva
             do n =1, nvb
               saps = oab(j, n+noccb)
               sbap = oab(j, k)
               sac = oac(i, l)
               scr = oac(m + nocca, l)
               im = i + nocca*(m-1)  
               kn = k + noccb*(n-1)
               imkn = im + oava*(kn-1)
               vrsab = ovovab(imkn)
   demp3 = demp3 + 2.0d0*vrsab*(2.0d0*saps*sbap*sac*scr)
             end do
           end do
         end do
       end do
     end do
   end do
```

I was trying to calculate saps*sac in the separate loop and similarly sac*scr:

```
c      Calculate saps * sbap 
       do j = 1, nocca
         do k  = 1, noccb
           do n = 1, nvb
             saps = oab(j, n + noccb)
             sbap = oab(j, k)   
             saps_sbap(j, k) = saps_sbap(j, k) + saps*sbap
           end do
         end do
       end do

c      Calculate sac_scr     
       do i = 1, nocca
         do l = 1, noccc
           do m = 1, nva
             sac = oac(i, l)
             scr = oac(m + nocca, l)
             sac_scr(i, l) = sac_scr(i, l) + sac*scr
           end do
         end do
       end do
```

Finally I would like to write the last part to calculate demp3 but there are 5 indices not 4 as I expected. Maybe I'm doing this entirely wrong?

Any suggestions? hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know that the loops are not already optimal?

Comment: A comment I would make is that you are not traversing the arrays in an optimal memory order. In Fortran, the leftmost array subscript varies fastest, yet your loops use the outermost loop for that index. This is a common mistake made by people who don't know Fortran well. Some compilers will rearrange the loops on their own, but you can help by doing so yourself.

Comment: I don't know. I don't even know what those variables are. This is part of computational program containing hundreds of such a construcions. This method is known as O(N^4) but this implementation is O(N^6). This is only one example. I need to reformat several of them but I don't know how to start. If I had one example I think I would be able to figure out the rest. The only way I'm able to check if it is working is to compile and run, then compare results of computations with the results obtained using original code.

Comment: The main idea is to split those multiplications to few smaller loops.

Comment: Modern Fortran compiler are good at hoisting invariant computations out of a loop.  First, you need a test case that exercises the loops to ensure any change does not adversely affect the outcome.  Next, you need to actually measure the execution time.  Now, start moving parts of the inner loop to outer loops to (possibly) minimize the number of computations.  For example, the multiplication of `2.0d0*sbap*sac` can be moved up 2 layers.

Comment: BTW - this isn't Fortran77, the vintage as shown is at least Fortran90

Comment: any explanation for -1?

Comment: Actually this program is written in fortran 77, I reformatted this loop to get rid of dumb number-references at the end of do statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly easier to downwote than try to understand a problem. I found optimal solution by myself. Here it is:

1. Split large sum into two components. Let's consider only the first one:

   `demp3 = demp3 + 2.0d0*vrsab*(2.0d0*saps*sbap*sac*scr)`
2. Multiply saps*sbap and sac*scr in two separate loops. (Dimensions can be found as maximal indices in the original loop):

   ```
   REAL*16, DIMENSION(nvb, noccb) :: saps_sbap
   REAL*16, DIMENSION(nocca, nva) :: sac_scr
   ```

following loops multiply saps*sbap and sac*scr:

```
c      Calculate saps * sbap 

   do k = 1, noccb
     do n = 1, nvb
       saps_sbap(n, k) = 0.0d0
       do j = 1, nocca
         saps = oab(j, n + noccb)
         sbap = oab(j, k)   
         saps_sbap(n, k) = saps_sbap(n, k) + saps*sbap
       end do
     end do
   end do 

c      Calculate sac * scr
   do i = 1, nocca
     do m = 1, nva
       sac_scr(i, m) = 0.0d0
       do l = 1, noccc
         sac = oac(i, l)
         scr = oac(m + nocca, l)
         sac_scr(i, m) = sac_scr(i, m) + sac*scr 
       end do
     end do
   end do
```

3. Finally put all things together in such a loop:

   `do i = 1, nocca
     do k = 1, noccb
       do m = 1, nva
         do n = 1, nvb
           im = i + nocca*(m-1)
           kn = k + noccb*(n-1)
           imkn = im +oava*(kn-1)
           vrsab = ovovab(imkn)
           demp3 = demp3 + 2.0d0 * vrsab * 2.0d0 *saps_sbap(n,k) * sac_scr(i,m)
         end do
       end do
     end do
   end do`

In such a way instead of O(N^6) loop there are two O(N^3) and one O(N^4)

Sorry for the last piece format, line-end didn't worked.